# Default route doesn't work

Tags: python, routes, pylons

I'm using the standard routing module with pylons to try and setup a default route for the home page of my website.

I've followed the instructions in the docs and here http://routes.groovie.org/recipes.html but when I try `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` I just get the 'Welcome to Pylons' default page.

My config/routing.py file looks like this

from pylons import config
from routes import Mapper

```
def make_map():
    """Create, configure and return the routes Mapper"""
    map = Mapper(directory=config['pylons.paths']['controllers'],
             always_scan=config['debug'])
    map.minimization = False

    map.connect('/error/{action}', controller='error')
    map.connect('/error/{action}/{id}', controller='error')

    # CUSTOM ROUTES HERE
    map.connect( '', controller='main', action='index' )
    map.connect('/{controller}/{action}')
    map.connect('/{controller}/{action}/{id}')

    return map
```

I've also tried 
    map.connect( '/', controller='main', action='index' )

and (using `http://127.0.0.1:5000/homepage/`)

```
map.connect( 'homepage', controller='main', action='index' )
```

But nothing works at all. I know its reloading my config file as I used 
     paster serve --reload development.ini 
to start the server

system info

```
$ paster --version
PasteScript 1.7.3 from /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/PasteScript-1.7.3-py2.5.egg (python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to delete the static page (myapp/public/index.html).  Static
files take priority due to the Cascade configuration at the end of
middleware.py.